Funny lattice equivalence between additive and subtractive extended square roots
I am interested in the behavior of the "extended square root", such as:
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}} ...$$
$$\sqrt{n\pm\sqrt{n\pm\sqrt{n\pm\sqrt{n\pm}}}} ...$$
I've noticed after running a python script to evaluate these, they usually converge to a value after 5 or so layers of the nested square root.
I have found that:
$$\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n}}}} = 1 + \sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}}}$$
and
$$\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+...}}}} * \sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n-...}}}} = n$$
But more interesting to me is the behvaior that these show on the interval of 'n', where:
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}} = \sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6}}}}$$
$$\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6}}}} = \sqrt{12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{12-\sqrt{12}}}}$$
$$\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12}}}} = \sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}}$$
Seems an easy way to construct these ugly monster squares, you can make these equality expressions at an index i with the following:
$$f(i)=i^2+i$$
$$f(i+1)=i^2-i$$
My question is, this sequence of equality follows
$$f(i) = 2*i + f(i-1)$$
$$(0,2,6,12,20,30,42,56,...)$$
This smells like a log rule to me, and I'd love some help associating it with that if anyone has an explanation. Feel free to correct me on anything I've got wrong here. I can also provide the python scripts I've been using to run these numbers. :)
desmos graphs of calculated values and their lines

Funny, laughed.
